# What happens with my messages and contacts after factory reset

Tags: backup, factory-reset, htc, htc-evo-3d

Lately i'm having some problems with my HTC EVO 3D.
It freezes all of a sudden, sometimes the screen doesn't respond well to touch etc, and i have to do a hard reset.

Since i believe it is due to a lot of apps i've installed etc, i decided to reset everything, and do a factory reset.

I don't care about the data of my apps or the data on my SD card (video and pics).

One thing i would like to backup is SMS and contacts. So, i'm guessing all my messages and contacts would be deleted when i do a factory reset. But, can you recommend a way to backup my messages and contacts, so i can restore them after the factory reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely correct with your assumption a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) will delete *all* your apps and data (as you also can find in the [factory-reset tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)).

If you want to backup your contacts *and* SMS, I'm afraid there's no native way. While the contacts you could sync with Google, the same cannot be said for SMS. But if you take a look at google play, [searching for the string "sms backup"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=sms%20backup) you will find a lot of helpful apps. Depending on your preferences, they can backup to your GMail account, or do it locally. Putting both things together, a good choice seems to be [Super Backup: SMS & Contacts](http://www.appbrain.com/app/super-backup-%3A-sms-contacts/com.idea.backup.smscontacts), which cares for both and can save the backup to either GMail or your SDCard. And of course it has a restore function as well.

Btw: On most devices, you easily can backup your contacts with the native *Contacts* app. It supports Export to/Import from VCard (`.vcf`) files (just open its menu from its main screen). No cloud involved. So you'd only need to check for something similar for your SMS, if you're concerned about privacy and want to avoid having them in the cloud.

Comment: I'll support the suggestion of Super Backup : SMS & Contacts. It's worked well for my friends who can't use Titanium Backup since they don't have root. Or just because Titanium's UI is impossible to navigate for 99% of the population.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'll try Super Backup, and hope it serves my needs ;)

Comment: I don't know about the Evo 3D, but on my Incredible S (on ICS), the stock messaging app had a backup/restore messages feature.